# Use the same function for different comboBox's

Tags: c#, combobox

How can I do this more efficiently? Ideally so I can call showTag without any arguments and it returns the correct comboBox.

I added the argument table to define whether the value returned by showTag was from comboBox1 or comboBox2. So if i want the value for comboBox1 I call showTag(1), if I want the value for comboBox2 I call showTag(2)

```
//Return the currently selected language
public string showTag(int table)
{
    string LanguageSelection = String.Empty;
    if (table == 1)
    {
        LanguageSelection = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        LanguageSelection = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
    string[] LanguageTag = LanguageSelection.Split(' ');
    string tag = LanguageTag[1].Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "");
    return tag;
}
```

Comment: How is `showTag` supposed to know which combo box you are trying to query without the argument? Is there any rule for that?

Comment: If you want to get rid of table, we have to know what it is and where it comes from.

Comment: Ideally I want all my programs to do exactly what I want, not what I wrote (or could have written) :)... but stupid code needs precise information to make any decisions.

Comment: I added the argument table to define whether the value returned by showTag was from comboBox1 or comboBox2. So if i want the value for comboBox1 I call showTag(1), if I want the value for comboBox2 I call showTag(2).

Comment: That is clear from your code, what missing is your meaning of "efficiently". Your code is ok (in sense it does what you described) so you need to clearly define what is wrong with it or which way you want to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add a SelectedIndexChanged event on the same function for your 2 combobox (go to properties of your two combobox and click event and SelectedIndexChanged)

```
private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
            ComboBox cb =  (ComboBox )sender ;
            LanguageSelection = cb.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string[] LanguageTag = LanguageSelection.Split(' ');
            //string tag have to be declared in your application at a global level
            tag = LanguageTag[1].Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "");

}
```

Comment: You cannot return a string from a void method and OP has not specified that he only need the information whenever a combobox is changed.

Comment: Is there any way that I could then pass this onto another function and preserve the knowledge of which comboBox it was? I need to update a dataGridView1 or dataGridView2 based on which comboBox was selected.

Comment: you can get the right combobox by check his name (cb.Name) that will return combobox1 or combobox2. so inside this event you can test the name and call the good dataGridView